# Similar Termquerys, but not similar output.. whats the difference?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I´ve got a problem with this. the first one works perfectly IMO,

```
QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "OrderId",
            Value = "1"
        };
        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index: "testindex")
        {
            Query = query
        };
        var searchResult = client.Search<TestLogs>(searchRequest);
  var orderIdArray = searchResult.Documents.ToArray();

  Console.WriteLine(orderIdArray[0])

  foreach (var s in orderIdArray)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"{i}:    OrderId:" + s.OrderID + " Event: " + s.Event + " Time: " + s.TimeStamp);
            i++;
        }
```

Now is the problem only that if I change

```
 QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "OrderId",
            Value = "1"
        };
```

to...

```
 QueryContainer query = new TermQuery()
        {
            Field = "Event",
            Value = "CreateOrder"
        };
```

It won't give any output in the Test method

> ELK_algorithmsTests.TestIndexCreation.testToMakeSameSelectionButWithSelectedEvent
>   threw exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ..

by looking in kibana i could read this
{
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "OrderId": "2",
          "Event": "StartOrder",
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-01 02:27:00"
        }
      },

any suggestion where it should look? because I'm out of ideas right now...

Comment: Where is `orderIdArray` defined? Does the type in `testindex` contain an `"Event"` field (_case sensitive_)? Where is the `IndexOutOfRangeException` actually thrown?

Comment: @RussCam  added the orderIdArray deffination, the exeption "indexOutOfRange" is thrown cause the array does not contains any data. so we can ignore that part. testidex does contain "Event" as a field. as far as i can see in kibana, see added codes above